# Fuzzy Matching using Soundex on SQL- Combination of tables

Tags: sql

Scenario: 
We have a table called AddressTable. 
In there we have 4 columns: 
AddressID int PK no nulls allowed
AddressLine1 nvarchar (255)
AddressLine2 nvarchar (255)
AddressLine3 nvarchar (255)

What kind of logic should I use to compare all the records using fuzzy matching relevant function to return me the IDs of possible duplicates?

```
select AddressID, SOUNDEX(AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3) from [AddressTable]
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a self join:

```
select distinct t1.*
from [AddressTable] t1
join [AddressTable] t2
  on t1.AddressID <> t2.AddressID and     
     SOUNDEX(t1.AddressLine1, t1.AddressLine2, t1.AddressLine3) =
     SOUNDEX(t2.AddressLine1, t2.AddressLine2, t2.AddressLine3)
```

Or, do an `EXISTS`:

```
select t1.*
from [AddressTable] t1
where exists (select * from [AddressTable] t2
              where t1.AddressID <> t2.AddressID
                and SOUNDEX(t1.AddressLine1, t1.AddressLine2, t1.AddressLine3) =
                    SOUNDEX(t2.AddressLine1, t2.AddressLine2, t2.AddressLine3))
```

Comment: I want to see the possible duplicates. By possible duplicates I mean. 
1, 1 Wonston Road, Southampton, UK
2, 1 Wnstn Roed, Hampshire, UK

Comment: Updated. Added alternative query.